# Storybook Global Scss variables

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, webpack, sass, storybook

CLI Tool: Storybook
Framework: Vue/ Nuxt

Issue: I'm trying to pull in global SCSS variables to Storybook Stories so they run the components the same way as they do in Nuxt, I've tried the custom webpack config with sass-resources-loader but had no luck, just wanted to check if anyone else has already solved this problem

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem. None of the answers on this thread are applicable at all, because I can get Storybook to read SCSS - that's not the problem. Storybook doesn't know how to read my global SCSS file that contains all my variables and mixins. You can't import them into main.js or preview.js either.

Comment: @keyboard-warrior I have EXACTLY the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11052) with Storybook handling multiple rules.

**I solved it by a work around**.

You can read the blog i wrote for detailed explaination [**here**](https://coder.rocks/posts/storybook-js-custom-webpack-setup-for-scss/).

**Below is my webpack config - *main.js* :**

```
webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.map((rule) => {
      if (rule.oneOf) {
        rule.oneOf = rule.oneOf.slice().map((subRule) => {
          if (subRule.test instanceof RegExp && subRule.test.test('.scss')) {
            return {
              ...subRule,
              use: [
                ...subRule.use,
                {
                  loader: require.resolve('sass-resources-loader'),
                  options: {
                    resources: [
                      path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/_common.scss')
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
            }
          }
          return subRule;
        });
      }
      return rule;
    });
    return config;
  },
```

**Hope this helps someone!**

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the issue where global SASS variables were causing Storybook for Vue to fail.

For me, creating a `webpack.config.js` file in the `.storybook` folder with the below configuration solved my problem:

```
module.exports = (storybookBaseConfig, configType, defaultConfig) => {

  defaultConfig.module.rules.push(
    {
      resourceQuery: /module/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'vue-style-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            shadowMode: false
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            importLoaders: 2,
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            indentedSyntax: true,
            data: '@import "@/sass/_variables.scss";'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  );

  return defaultConfig;
};
```

Note the line `data: '@import "@/sass/_variables.scss";'` needs to match the file path for the SASS file with variables in your project.

This section of config was retrieved from Vue CLI 3 by running `vue inspect > output.js` and then copying the config for the rule `test: /\.sass$/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scss rule in your `.storybook/webpack.config.js` for storybook to parse `scss`.

```
const path = require('path');
const scss = {
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    'vue-style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    'sass-loader'
  ],
};
module.exports = (storybookBaseConfig, configType, defaultConfig) => {
  defaultConfig.module.rules.push(scss);

  return defaultConfig;
};
```

You may also need to install the appropriate loaders:

`yarn add -D vue-style-loader sass-loader css-loader`

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who can actually get Storybook to read SCSS files but can't get it to read the global variables file, do this in your custom webpack config:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    // Apply loader
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            prependData: '@import "path/to/global.scss";',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Storybook 7 and React framework with `@storybook/addon-styling-webpack` to handle loading my Sass files. I was able to prepend my Sass variables and other global styles with the Storybook config below. I needed to use `additionalData` rather than `prependData` in the sass-loader options to prepend my global stylesheets:

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";
import path from 'path';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-themes",
    ({
        name: "@storybook/addon-styling-webpack",
        options: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              use: [
                  "style-loader",
                  "css-loader",
                  {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: { 
                      implementation: require.resolve("sass"),
                      additionalData: `@import "${ path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/global.styles.scss") }";`
                    }
                  },
              ],
            }
          ],
        }
    })
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-webpack5",
    options: {
      builder: {
        useSWC: true,
      },
    },
  },
  swc: () => ({
    jsc: {
      transform: {
        react: {
          runtime: "automatic"
        }
      }
    }
  }),
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  }
};
export default config;
```

Answer (score -2):

If your components do not get styles applied when run in the Storybook component explorer UI, just import SASS styles in your main Storybook `config/storybook/config.js` (in previous versions was by default at `storybook/config.js`) like so:

```js
// Import Styles
import '../../src/assets/styles/index.scss';
```

Usually you'd have your styles and plugins imported in your `src/main.js` / `src/main.ts` but you also need to do this in Storybook config, as when running Storybook it's not running the whole Vue app but just those individual components.