# How to setup Storybook with Create React App to use global sass mixins

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, storybook, craco

I have an app made with Create React App, and want to use Storybook with it.

My app uses scss modules, so I am using [CRACO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) to ensure my global scss variables and mixins are available in my scss modules. My CRACO config looks like this:

```js
const sassResourcesLoader = require('craco-sass-resources-loader');
const sassInject = require.resolve('./src/css/global.scss');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: sassResourcesLoader,
      options: {
        resources: sassInject,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Of course, this config is not used by Storybook.

The default storybook config files look like the following:

```js
// .storybook/main.js
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../src/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app'
  ],
};
```

```js
// .storybook/preview.js
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

I found some documentation that suggested something along the lines of these, which should allow adding the config I'm using with CRACO into storybook:

```js
// .storybook/main.js
const sassResourcesLoader = require('craco-sass-resources-loader');
const sassInject = require.resolve('../src/css/global.scss');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/preset-create-react-app'],
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    config.plugins.push({
      plugin: sassResourcesLoader,
      options: {
        resources: sassInject,
      },
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

Unfortunately this just results in errors:

```
info @storybook/react v6.2.9
info 
info => Loading presets
info => Serving static files from ./public at /
info => Loading 1 config file in "/Users/Me/myApp/.storybook"
info => Loading 7 other files in "/Users/Me/myApp/.storybook"
info => Adding stories defined in "/Users/Me/myApp/.storybook/main.js"
info => Using prebuilt manager
info => Loading Webpack configuration from `node_modules/react-scripts`
info => Removing existing JavaScript and TypeScript rules.
info => Modifying Create React App rules.
info => Using default Webpack4 setup
ERR! WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
ERR!  - configuration.plugins[14] misses the property 'apply'.
ERR!    function
ERR!    -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
ERR!     at Object.webpack [as get] (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:31:9)
ERR!     at Object.start (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/dist/cjs/index.js:92:27)
ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
ERR!     at async storybookDevServer (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/dev-server.js:103:28)
ERR!     at async buildDevStandalone (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:107:31)
ERR!     at async buildDev (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:147:5)
ERR!  WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
ERR!  - configuration.plugins[14] misses the property 'apply'.
ERR!    function
ERR!    -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
ERR!     at Object.webpack [as get] (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:31:9)
ERR!     at Object.start (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/dist/cjs/index.js:92:27)
ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
ERR!     at async storybookDevServer (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/dev-server.js:103:28)
ERR!     at async buildDevStandalone (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:107:31)
ERR!     at async buildDev (/Users/Me/myApp/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:147:5)
```

How can I successfully get Storybook to import my scss variables and mixins?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using storybook-preset-craco package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [storybook-preset-craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/storybook-preset-craco) package, which provides a one-line craco configuration for Storybook.

Comment: Thanks, I've given this a go but without success, getting odd errors from the scss files:

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
on line 1 of /Users/me/MyApp/src/js/components/partials/Icon/Icon.module.scss
```

I found others getting this same issue, and tried a few solutions including this, which does at least compile without errors, but sadly still doesn't seem to let me use my mixins or variables:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62236463/1818129

Comment: @PrimalAnomaly I'm getting the same issue - did you resolve it? --- note my use of CRACO is only for craco-alias - so I'm not messing with the SCSS part at all and it still fails like this.

Comment: @Julix unfortunately not, I ended up just importing my vars and mixins in every component CSS file and never came back to trying to resolve it, sorry

Comment: I managed to get it fixed! The solution was that it was transpiled twice -commenting out '@storybook/preset-create-react-app' in the addons did it for me - it's apparently not needed with craco